# When I create a new VM using Azure Powershell I get no public IP Address. Why?

Tags: azure, powershell

I just started playing around with Azure Powershell and I'm trying to create a new Azure VM.

Script:

```
$username = 'demoadmin'

$password = ConvertTo-SecureString 'Password123!@#' -AsPlainText -Force

$WindowsCred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($username, $password)

New-AzVM -ResourceGroup 'psdemo-rg-uksouth' -Name 'psdemo-win-az' -Image 'win2016datacenter' -Size 'Standard_D2ads_v5' -Credential $WindowsCred -OpenPorts 3389
```

Result: Azure VM is successfully created, but there is no Public IP address assigned.

Looking at the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.compute/new-azvm?view=azps-8.0.0) I can see the description for parameter "PublicIpAddressName": "The name of a new (or existing) public IP address for the created VM to use. If not specified, a name will be generated.".

How can I make it assign a Public IP Address on creation?

Comment: There is an example of using `New-AzPublicIpAddress` and assigning it on the linked page you provided

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I saw it, but I was hoping I don't have to do that as it's rather complicated for something that is done automatically in Azure CLI.
This command creates a VM with public IP by default. 
az vm create --resource-group psdemo-rg-westeurope --name win-CLI-demo --image win2016datacenter --size Standard_D2ads_v5 --admin-username demoadmin --admin-password Password123!@#

Comment: Check whether you're using the latest module version? Try to do the same thing using a different machine or using the CloudShell?

Answer (score 0):

When I run the PowerShell commands you provided, yes - it is not provisioned the Public IP address, but it will be assigned the Private IP Address by Azure dynamically.

[image]

If you do not pass the PublicIpAddressName parameter, then it will not be created automatically:

[image]

Following these MSFT [Doc1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.compute/new-azvm?view=azps-8.0.0) & [Doc 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/tutorial-manage-vm#create-a-vm), we have to pass the Public IP Address parameter to get assigned to the associated Virtual Machine by Azure.

**PowerShell Script I used to get the Public IP Address while VM Creation in Azure**:

```
#Create the Virtual Network
$vnet = @{
    Name = 'myVNet'
    ResourceGroupName = 'HariTestRg'
    Location = 'EastUS'
    AddressPrefix = '10.0.0.0/16'    
}
$virtualNetwork = New-AzVirtualNetwork @vnet

#Create the Subnet
$subnet = @{
    Name = 'default'
    VirtualNetwork = $virtualNetwork
    AddressPrefix = '10.0.0.0/24'
}
$subnetConfig = Add-AzVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig @subnet

$virtualNetwork | Set-AzVirtualNetwork

#Create the Virtual Machine by passing the Public IP Address parameter
$username = '<your-user-name>'
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString '<your-password>' -AsPlainText -Force
$WindowsCred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($username, $password)
New-AzVm `
    -ResourceGroupName "HariTestRg" `
    -Name "psdemo-win-az02" `
    -Location "EastUS" `
    -VirtualNetworkName "myVnet" `
    -SubnetName "default" `
    -SecurityGroupName "myNetworkSecurityGroup" `
    -PublicIpAddressName "myPublicIpAddress2" `
    -ImageName "MicrosoftWindowsServer:WindowsServer:2016-Datacenter-with-Containers:latest" `
    -Credential $WindowsCred
```

**Result**:

[image: VM Creation Using PowerShell Script to get PublicIP]